# AngularJS - Using a directive to produce a <td> not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a large set of repeated HTML for which i am trying to create a directive for. I have created directives in the past, mainly on DIV's, but this is the first time trying on a `<table>` / `<td>`.

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="entries in Categories">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="history in entries.InfoEntries">
                <th>
                    {{ history.Name }}
                </th>
                <!-- Trying to produce directive of this <td> -->
                <td ng-repeat="status in history.History.slice(0, 12) track by $index">
                    <span ng-switch="status">
                        <span ng-switch-when="0"></span>
                        <span ng-switch-when="U">U</span>
                        <span ng-switch-when="D">D</span>
                        <span ng-switch-when="1">1</span>
                        <span ng-switch-when="2">2</span>
                        <span ng-switch-when="3">3</span>
                        <span ng-switch-when="4">4</span>
                        <span ng-switch-when="5">5</span>
                        <span ng-switch-when="6">6</span>
                        <span ng-switch-default></span>
                    </span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="history in entries.InfoEntries">
                <th>
                    {{ history.Name }}
                </th>
                <!-- Trying to produce directive of this <td> -->
                <td ng-repeat="status in history.History.slice(12, 24) track by $index">
                    <span ng-switch="status">
                        <span ng-switch-when="0"></span>
                        <span ng-switch-when="U">U</span>
                        <span ng-switch-when="D">D</span>
                        <span ng-switch-when="1">1</span>
                        <span ng-switch-when="2">2</span>
                        <span ng-switch-when="3">3</span>
                        <span ng-switch-when="4">4</span>
                        <span ng-switch-when="5">5</span>
                        <span ng-switch-when="6">6</span>
                        <span ng-switch-default></span>
                    </span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="history in entries.InfoEntries">
                <th>
                    {{ history.Name }}
                </th>
                <!-- Trying to produce directive of this <td> -->
                <td ng-repeat="status in history.History.slice(24, 36) track by $index">
                    <span ng-switch="status">
                        <span ng-switch-when="0"></span>
                        <span ng-switch-when="U">U</span>
                        <span ng-switch-when="D">D</span>
                        <span ng-switch-when="1">1</span>
                        <span ng-switch-when="2">2</span>
                        <span ng-switch-when="3">3</span>
                        <span ng-switch-when="4">4</span>
                        <span ng-switch-when="5">5</span>
                        <span ng-switch-when="6">6</span>
                        <span ng-switch-default></span>
                    </span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

As you can see from the above, this only thing that changes from the `<table>`'s above is the range of values in the `.slice` -  so i'll pass them into my directive via:

```
<td history-status slice-status-history-start-range='0' slice-status-history-end-range='12'></td>
```

My directive:

```
app.directive('historyStatus', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: false,
    transclude: true,
    template:   '<td ng-repeat="status in history.History.slice(sliceStartRange, sliceEndRange) track by $index">' +
                    '<span ng-switch="status">' +                            
                        '<span ng-switch-when="U">U</span>' +
                        '<span ng-switch-when="D">D</span>' +
                        '<span ng-switch-when="1">1</span>' +
                        '<span ng-switch-when="2">2</span>' +
                        '<span ng-switch-when="3">3</span>' +
                        '<span ng-switch-when="4">4</span>' +
                        '<span ng-switch-when="5">5</span>' +
                        '<span ng-switch-when="6">6</span>' +
                        '<span ng-switch-default></span>' +
                    '</span>' +
                '</td>',
    scope: {
        sliceStartRange: '=sliceStatusHistoryStartRange',
        sliceEndRange: '=sliceStatusHistoryEndRange'
    }
  };
});
```

With the above, the directive is not diaplying any results, nor are any errors appearing in the console.

Comment: try changing the directive to restrict: 'E' and putting the element in the html. <historyStatus slice-status-history-start-range='0' slice-status-history-end-range='12></historyStatus

Comment: @AlexScott - tried your suggestion, didn't work. Are the replace: false, transclude: true variables ok? With my original suggestion, i could see the markup being injected into the HTML, but data wasnt being bound.

Comment: try changing replace to true, you want your TD's code in the table to be replaced as you cant have TD's inside TD's

Comment: You code results in having an couple of `<td>`'s in a `<td>`. The result is that it will not display. If you look in the inspector, you will probably see all your `<td>`'s.
This is one of the reasons there is an comment directive possible. Have a look at the restrict part of the documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile

Comment: Oh, BTW, I assume your spans will contain something more then just this? If not, consider this:
`<span> {{ "UD123456".indexOf(status)>-1 ? status : '' }}</span>`

Comment: @SanderElias - your solution looks interesting, tell me more about that syntax? I need to apply a css class on each span too.

Comment: @OamPsy, What do you want to hear? If I look at your code, it looks like you want to to display only certain status's This can be done with the indeOf function too, and then use the output of that with the ternary operator. Same trick can be done for the class or ng-class operator too. 
If you need it in 2 places you can use ng-init to store the result of the comparison.
hmm, I will build you a sample, that's easier!

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is you've isolated the directive's scope, which means you need to explicitly pass 'history' there:

**HTML:**

```
<td history-status history="history" slice-status-history-start-range='0' slice-status-history-end-range='12'></td>
```

**In your directive:**

```
scope: {
        sliceStartRange: '=sliceStatusHistoryStartRange',
        sliceEndRange: '=sliceStatusHistoryEndRange',
        history: '='
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you will be producing an invalid markup, because you will be adding a 'td' inside a 'td'..

set replace to 'true'.
plkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/hk9GJ7tiL0VANhcSiBax?p=preview

```
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.js"></script>
<script>
  angular.module("ng").directive('historyStatus', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        template:   '<td ng-repeat="status in datasrc track by $index">' +
                       '<span ng-switch="status">' +                            
                            '<span ng-switch-when="U">U</span>' +
                            '<span ng-switch-when="D">D</span>' +
                            '<span ng-switch-when="1">1</span>' +
                            '<span ng-switch-when="2">2</span>' +
                            '<span ng-switch-when="3">3</span>' +
                            '<span ng-switch-when="4">4</span>' +
                            '<span ng-switch-when="5">5</span>' +
                            '<span ng-switch-when="6">6</span>' +
                            '<span ng-switch-default></span>' +
                        '</span>' +
                    '</td>',
        scope: {
            sliceStartRange: '=sliceStatusHistoryStartRange',
            sliceEndRange: '=sliceStatusHistoryEndRange',
            datasrc: '=datasrc'
        }
      };
    }).run(function($rootScope){

    });
</script>
</head>

<body ng-app>
  <table ng-init="datasrc=['1','2','3','4','U','A']">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td datasrc="datasrc" history-status slice-status-history-start-range='0' slice-status-history-end-range='12'></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

[here is the sample](http://plnkr.co/edit/3iKJgE5eHtkSdEak8QTQ?p=preview) I promised you.

If you still have questions, don't hesitate to ask!

you can use the hasStatus scope variable in classes too.

```
   <span> {{ "UD123456".indexOf(status)>-1 ? status : '-' }}</span>
```

Does this help a bit?